# Browser not switching to view explicitly called

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a rather strange issue where I have a button in my Index which is linked to some Javascript which then calls my IndicatorController StepTwo ActionResult which after it hits the return View line in the debugger does the following:

1. Hits _ViewStart
2. Hits StepTwo's ViewBag.Title line
3. Quickly followed by going through _Layout
4. Hits Dispose function in Controller

However, the browser itself does not get directed to Indicator/StepTwo and I suspect it might be because the rest of the StepTwo view isn't being hit, but I'm not sure why that is.

StepTwo ActionMethod:

```
public ActionResult StepTwo(int wwStart, int wwEnd)
{
    if (!wwStart.Equals(null))
    {
        ViewBag.wwStartSelected = wwStart;
    }

    if (!wwEnd.Equals(null))
    {
        ViewBag.wwEndSelected = wwEnd;
    }
    return View("StepTwo");
}
```

StepTwo View:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create Indicator: Step 2 of 3";
}

<h2>Create Indicator: Step 2 of 3 - Select Work Week Range</h2>

<h3>Select Indicator Type</h3>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Manager Indicator</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Owner Indicator</button>
```

Index:

```
@model IEnumerable<YourProject.ViewModels.DropDownVM>



@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create Indicator: Step One of Two";
}

<h2>Indicators</h2>


<h2>Create Indicator: Step One of Two - Select Work Week Range</h2>

<h3>Select Starting Work Week</h3>

@Html.DropDownList("WWStart", (SelectList)ViewBag.DDLWWStart.Categories, " -- Select Starting Work Week -- ")
<br /><br />

<h3>Select Ending Work Week</h3>

@Html.DropDownList("WWEnd", (SelectList)ViewBag.DDLWWEnd.Categories, " -- Select Ending Work Week -- ")
<br /><br />

@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<button class="btn btn-default" id="checkbtn" onclick="nextStep();" type="button">Next Step</button>



<script type="text/javascript">
    function nextStep() {

        var wwStartElement = document.getElementById("WWStart");
        var wwStartValue = parseInt(wwStartElement.value);

        var wwEndElement = document.getElementById("WWEnd");
        var wwEndValue = parseInt(wwEndElement.value);

        if (wwStartValue > wwEndValue) {
            alert("You selected a starting Work Week that starts before the ending Work Week. Please select a starting Work Week that is equal to or happens before the ending Work Week.");
            return false;
        }

        alert("Right before issue?");
        //Submit data to IndictatorController/StepTwo ActionMethod
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("StepTwo")',
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                'wwStart': wwStartValue,
                'wwEnd': wwEndValue
            },
            success: function (result) {
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(thrownError);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: what does your JavaScript look like?

Comment: I added the Javascript for reference.

Comment: I'm sorry but I seem to have hard time understanding your situation.
Can you please elaborate what you want to do?

Comment: Index view has a javascript method which calls ActionResult StepTwo via Ajax which then calls the View StepTwo. However the browser isn't redirected to StepTwo view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's a fundamental misunderstanding here. If you're submitting an AJAX request, it's not going to cause the browser to do *anything*. The server response from the AJAX request will simply be passed to the success callback, and then it's up to *you* to decide what happens with it (insert something into the DOM, etc.). However, for this, you wouldn't want to return a full view, with layout and everything. That does you know good. Instead, you'd want something like a partial view, so that you can then just insert that HTML somewhere in the DOM.

If all you want to do is load a new web page into the browser tab/window, then JavaScript shouldn't even come into play. Just do a standard form post or make the button a link.

Comment: So doing:`'@Url.Action("StepTwo")'` and even though the debugger goes through the ActionResult and the top part of StepTwo view it won't actually call the browser to go to the view unless I do so in the success callback in the Javascript?

Comment: Yes, the server is still responding. It received a request and it's dutifully completing it. However, when the browser receives the response, it's routed to the AJAX callback because that's where the request originated.